# 404 config.json error for server deployment of ArcGIS Web AppBuilder Application?

Tags: json, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I am receving  a 404 error that my config.json cannot be found, I have added the JSON mime type to my IIS configuration at the site and server levels and have restarted IIS.  This error appears as so in my console  with other errors which I think are caused by the initial 404 of the config.json.  What other steps can be taken to remedy this?  Additionally when I hit the index.html I receive  an "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" error

`GET http://gisdev01/LifeSupportApplication/LifeSupportApplication/jimu.js/css/fonts/c4352a95-7a41-48c1-83ce-d8ffd2a3b118.woff 
main.js?wab_dv=2.1:1521 jimu.js init...
init.js:140 GET http://gisdev01/LifeSupportApplication/LifeSupportApplication/config.json?wab_dv=2.1 404 (Not Found)h @ init.js:140_tryLoadConfig @ main.js?wab_dv=2.1:236loadConfig @ main.js?wab_dv=2.1:227loadConfig @ main.js?wab_dv=2.1:11f.initApp @ main.js?wab_dv=2.1:1522(anonymous function) @ init.js:200ia @ init.js:28(anonymous function) @ init.js:28ja @ init.js:28ga @ init.js:28b @ init.js:29f @ init.js:151d @ init.js:152
init.js:113 TypeError: Cannot read property 'portalUrl' of undefined(…) "TypeError: Cannot read property 'portalUrl' of undefined
    at _addDefaultPortalUrl (http://gisdev01/LifeSupportApplication/LifeSupportApplication/jimu.js/main.js?wab_dv=2.1:32:492)
    at _addDefaultValues (http://gisdev01/LifeSupportApplication/LifeSupportApplication/jimu.js/main.js?wab_dv=2.1:31:416)
    at .<anonymous> (http://gisdev01/LifeSupportApplication/LifeSupportApplication/jimu.js/main.js?wab_dv=2.1:11:456)
    at http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:63:209
    at h (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:107:279)
    at k (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:107:205)
    at g.resolve (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:109:280)
    at a (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:108:148)
    at h (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:107:419)
    at k (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:107:205)
    ----------------------------------------
    rejected at a (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:108:174)
    at h (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:107:438)
    at k (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:107:205)
    at g.resolve (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:109:280)
    at a (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:108:148)
    at h (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:107:419)
    at k (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:107:205)
    at g.w.reject (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:109:488)
    at a (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:108:174)
    at h (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:107:452)
    ----------------------------------------
Error
    at then.c.then (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:110:97)
    at loadConfig (http://gisdev01/LifeSupportApplication/LifeSupportApplication/jimu.js/main.js?wab_dv=2.1:11:361)
    at Object.f.initApp (http://gisdev01/LifeSupportApplication/LifeSupportApplication/jimu.js/main.js?wab_dv=2.1:1522:55)
    at http://gisdev01/LifeSupportApplication/LifeSupportApplication/init.js:200:24
    at ia (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:28:3)
    at http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:28:256
    at ja (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:28:125)
    at ga (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:28:198)
    at b (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:29:177)
    at f (http://js.arcgis.com/3.17/init.js:151:195)"m @ init.js:113(anonymous function) @ init.js:114filter @ init.js:71h @ init.js:114`